# Control dot colour in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I control the colour of the dots in the scatter plot by ggplot2? I need the first 20 points to have a colour, then the next 20 to have a different colour. At the moment I am using base R plot output. The matrix looks like this

```
1 4
1 3
2 9
-1 8
9 9
```

and I have a colour vector which looks like

```
cols<-c("#B8DBD3","#FFB933","#FF6600","#0000FF")
```

then

```
plot(mat[,1],mat[,2],col=cols)
```

works.

How could I do this ggplot?

---

Regarding the colours

my cols vector looks ike this 
100->n

```
colours<-c(rep("#B8DBD3",n),rep("#FFB933",n),rep("#FF6600",n),rep("#0000FF",n),rep("#00008B",n),rep("#ADCD00",n),rep("#008B00",n),rep("#9400D3",n))
```

when I then do

```
d<-ggplot(new,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,col=rr))
d+theme_bw() +
  scale_color_identity(breaks = rep(colours, each = 1)) +
  geom_point(pch=21,size=7)
```

the colours look completely different from 
plot(new[,1],new[,2],col=colours)
this looks like
http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150417/2wwvq9u2.jpg
while ggplot with the same colours looks like

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150417/bwc5wn7b.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a column that designates to which group a point belongs to.

```
library(ggplot2)
xy <- data.frame(x = rnorm(80), y = rnorm(80), col = as.factor(rep(1:4, each = 20)))

cols<-c("#B8DBD3","#FFB933","#FF6600","#0000FF")

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y, col = col)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I would need to be ablte to define the own colours palette...which would tehn need to have 20 items right?...or how would i use the colours suggested in the post above?

Comment: the example works but tmy data are continuous adn i would need to set the palette my own because of specific cols...

Comment: @triub I switched the line that controls the scale. See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_identity.html I would look at ColorBrewer palettes, though...

Comment: how come that the colours in cols have changed from usage in normal graphic to ggplot2? there is no black in th ecols...

Comment: just if you preview the colours in an hex editor it is clear that there is no red or something..ion normal R output the colours look like this   http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150417/2wwvq9u2.jpg

Comment: @triub I think I nailed it this time. :)